# Como chamar a activity/fragment ao clicar no botão? Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou  começando a pouco tempo com programação, já pesquisei muito mas preciso de ajuda nesta duvida

Vou utilizar um menu no meu app, chamado Boom Menu 
https://github.com/Nightonke/BoomMenu

A minha dúvida é, onde que coloco a referência para chamar a activity ao clicar no botão?

Ja revirei a biblioteca inteira, e não faço a mínima idéia

Alguém ja utilizou ou sabe onde que coloca?

Escolhi este estilo de botão do código abaixo:

**Easeactivity.java**

```
package com.nightonke.boommenusample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.nightonke.boommenu.BoomMenuButton;

public class EaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ease);

        initBmb(R.id.bmb4);

    }

    private BoomMenuButton initBmb(int res) {
        BoomMenuButton bmb = (BoomMenuButton) findViewById(res);
        assert bmb != null;
        for (int i = 0; i < bmb.getPiecePlaceEnum().pieceNumber(); i++)
            bmb.addBuilder(BuilderManager.getSimpleCircleButtonBuilder());
        return bmb;
    }
}
```

**activity_ease.xml**

```
<com.nightonke.boommenu.BoomMenuButton
    android:id="@+id/bmb4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    app:bmb_normalColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    app:bmb_highlightedColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    app:bmb_buttonEnum="simpleCircle"
    app:bmb_piecePlaceEnum="piecePlace_dot_9_1"
    app:bmb_buttonPlaceEnum="buttonPlace_sc_9_1"
    app:bmb_showMoveEaseEnum="outElastic"
    app:bmb_showScaleEaseEnum="outElastic"
    app:bmb_showRotateEaseEnum="outElastic"
    app:bmb_hideMoveEaseEnum="inElastic"
    app:bmb_hideScaleEaseEnum="inElastic"
    app:bmb_hideRotateEaseEnum="inElastic"
    app:bmb_showDelay="0"
    app:bmb_hideDelay="0"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu acho mais simples dessa forma.

```
public void abrirActivity(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MinhaActivityQuevaiAbrir.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Lembrando que no atributo do seu botão deve colocar no onclick o seu metodo abrirActivity. os Atributos fica do lado direito do Android Studio.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Stênio, o botão é apenas um, mas abre mais 6 botões, se eu fizer do seu jeito, só vai abrir uma activity? Tem outro jeito para fazer?

Comment: Vi o link que passou, você quer chamar vários botões pelo botão flutuante da Activity. O que eu entendi é que você queria chamar uma Activity. Outra coisa você já baixou o exemplo do link.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, Michael!

Geralmente, você deve referenciar suas `Views` no método `onCreate` da sua `Activity`.
No caso da biblioteca, você pode usa-lá da seguinte forma

Obtenha sua `View`, o botão, e diga seu tipo

```
public class EaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ease);

        BoomMenuButton bmb = (BoomMenuButton) findViewById(res);
                       // Isso define o tipo do botão
                       bmb.setButtonEnum(ButtonEnum.SimpleCircle);
                       bmb.setPiecePlaceEnum(PiecePlaceEnum.DOT_3_1);

    }
}
```

Agora, segundo a documentação, você deve adicionar os "botões de extensão"

```
public class EaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ease);

        BoomMenuButton bmb = (BoomMenuButton) findViewById(res);
                       // Isso define o tipo do botão
                       bmb.setButtonEnum(ButtonEnum.SimpleCircle);
                       bmb.setPiecePlaceEnum(PiecePlaceEnum.DOT_3_1);

       for (int i = 0; i < bmb.getPiecePlaceEnum().pieceNumber(); i++) {
            SimpleCircleButton.Builder builder = new SimpleCircleButton.Builder()
               .normalImageRes(R.drawable.jellyfish); // Você pode setar para cada no sub-botão um ícone diferente

            bmb.addBuilder(builder);
       }
    }
}
```

Por último, você provavelmente vai querer saber quando algum dos botões for clicado, então é só anexar o evento de clique

```
public class EaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ease);

        BoomMenuButton bmb = (BoomMenuButton) findViewById(res);
                       // Isso define o tipo do botão
                       bmb.setButtonEnum(ButtonEnum.SimpleCircle);
                       bmb.setPiecePlaceEnum(PiecePlaceEnum.DOT_3_1);

       for (int i = 0; i < bmb.getPiecePlaceEnum().pieceNumber(); i++) {
            SimpleCircleButton.Builder builder = new SimpleCircleButton.Builder()
               .normalImageRes(R.drawable.jellyfish); // Você pode setar para cada no botão um ícone diferente

            builder.listener(new OnBMClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBoomButtonClick(int index) {
                  // Pra saber qual o botão que foi clicado, uso index          
                // Digamos que você queira que o segundo botão de extensão abra outra tela [Activity] e levando em conta que a biblioteca considera o primeiro índice como 0, o segundo será 1
                  if (index == 1) startActivity(new Intent(EaseActivity.this, ActivityDeDestino.class));
                }
            });
            bmb.addBuilder(builder);
       }

      // A documentação não deixa claro, mas acredito que você deve chamar o método build();
      bmb.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação! Não tava entendendo, agora ja deu uma esclarecida, vou tentar novamente amanhã. Quero colocar 6 botões, e cada um chamando uma activity diferente, vou tentar!